# Fastest implementation to iteratively copy the previous row and then randomly overwrite one cell

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization

This code is slow for `n.col=31; n.row=1600000`, and I can't think of how to optimize it in R. I need to know the balance of several items at each step, but only one balance changes per step. I have a vector of balance updates, `data`, and an index vector, `col.i`, that tells which item the balance updates pertain to. From those, I aim to produce a data frame showing the balance of each item at each step, one row per step.

```
n.col = 31;   n.row = 1600000
col.i <- sample( 1:n.col, size=n.row, replace=T)
data <- rnorm( n=n.row, mean=0, sd=1)
grid <- as.data.frame( matrix( ncol=n.col, nrow=n.row, data=0))

grid[ 1, col.i[1]] <- data[1]
for(i in 2:nrow(grid))
{
    grid[i,] <- grid[i-1,]
    grid[i, col.i[i]] <-data[i]
}
```

Comment: I bet it would be much faster with a matrix, not data frame. Is this an option?

Comment: @Andrey Yeah I can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We make this more faster by assigning values based on `row/column` indexing (in addition to keeping the 'grid' as a `matrix` instead of `data.frame` - as @AndreyShabalin mentioned in the comments)

```
library(zoo)
system.time({
grid[ 1, col.i[1]] <- data[1]

for(i in 2:nrow(grid))
{
    grid[i,] <- grid[i-1,]
    grid[i, col.i[i]] <-data[i]
}

})
# user  system elapsed 
#   8.36    0.16    8.57 



system.time({
grid2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(grid2)), col.i)] <- data
grid2 <- na.locf(grid2*(NA^!grid2), na.rm = FALSE)
grid2 <- replace(grid2, is.na(grid2), 0)

})
#  user  system elapsed 
#   3.50    2.01    5.52 
identical(grid, grid2)
#[1] TRUE
```

The bottleneck in the above would be `na.locf`

#### data

```
n.col = 31;   n.row = 1600000
set.seed(24)
col.i <- sample( n.col, size=n.row, replace=T)
data <- rnorm( n=n.row, mean=0, sd=1)
grid <- matrix( ncol=n.col, nrow=n.row, data=0)
grid2 <- grid
```